# Jasper Report with Navigation Bar on Left side

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need a Jasper Report which has 10 sub reports.all of the reports should execute first (on background of Jasper Server) but display it only when we click on the hyper link on the navigation bar left side. Also I need tabs underneath the main report with same name as that of navigation bar hyper links
I am attaching My requirement that developed on wib reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  achieved this on two ways :-

1. Created local anchors and Placed the hyper link anchors on the background  band so it act as a separate menu item.
2. Create a custom jsp input control with hyper link and value as the anchor name you have given or you can add the url of the report to be executed after the click. eg:-http://localhost:8080/reportservice/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Forganizations%2FCareFirst%2Fca_ppm%2FReportsCustom&reportUnit=%2Forganizations%2FCareFirst%2Fca_ppm%2FReportsCustom%2FPMO_Metrics_Extract_Report&standAlone=true&parameter1=2015&parameter2=600824

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want pdf reports and you ahttp://www.rtssys.com/blog/archives/118.htmlre using iReports designer.
What you need is a hyperlink / anchor to different pages in the navigation bars (side and bottom). You can generate all the pages in one go with each page containing your navigation bars. You can copy / paste the same in all pages.
Next you link your pages with your hyperlinks using anchors/hyperlinks.

Here are a few references:
http://www.rtssys.com/blog/archives/118.html

http://passionfordata.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-add-hyperlinks-in-jasper-server.html
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540185/simple-hyperlink-text-field-same-report-works-ireport-not-jasperserver

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Arnab.. But what exaclty my requirement is I need a left side Menu Bar which contains the names of all the sub reports and it should remain static through out the report execution..and if I click the hyperlink or whatsoever report should execute like we pressing on a tab button in excel sheet..Simply I need a report in jasper server with a left side menu bar and sub reports displaying like excel sheets.. Thanks again for your anticipation...

Comment: One more thing ..Do we have any facility to include any html or jsp pages inside jasper server as a Report and call the Jrxml's inside the JSP or ?HTML tags..

Comment: I am sorry but jsp or html inclusion is not supported in jasper. jasper reports are meant to be static reports. once it is generated you cannot modify the same or generate sub reports from it. the operation has to be atomic. if you are talking of an web ui that would generate reports you can do the same in jsp/html. then on each click of the tab, you can send call to the server to generate the report, and show it in the browser itself. sketch me a prototype of what exactly you want.